# How can I get a list from a Ruby enumerable?

Tags: ruby, list, iterator, enumerable

I know of Python's `list` method that can consume all elements from a generator. Is there something like that available in Ruby?

I know of :

```
elements = []
enumerable.each {|i| elements << i}
```

I also know of the `inject` alternative. Is there some ready available method?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Enumerable#to_a`

Comment: Ruby 2.0 introduce `Enumerator::Lazy` that has `#to_a` and `#force` (for the same purpose). You can read more here [Ruby 2.0 Enumerable::Lazy](http://railsware.com/blog/2012/03/13/ruby-2-0-enumerablelazy/)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do some transformation on all the elements in your enumerable, the #collect (a.k.a. #map) method would be helpful:

```
elements = enumerable.collect { |item| item.to_s }
```

In this example, `elements` will contain all the elements that are in `enumerable`, but with each of them translated to a string.  E.g.

```
enumerable = [1, 2, 3]
elements = enumerable.collect { |number| number.to_s }
```

In this case, `elements` would be `['1', '2', '3']`.

Here is some output from irb illustrating the difference between `each` and `collect`:

```
irb(main):001:0> enumerable = [1, 2, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):002:0> elements = enumerable.each { |number| number.to_s }
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):003:0> elements
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):004:0> elements = enumerable.collect { |number| number.to_s }
=> ["1", "2", "3"]
irb(main):005:0> elements
=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: Nothing would prevent me from doing that in `each`.

Comment: Geo: the difference between `each` and `collect` is that `each` does not return an array, whereas `collect` does. Hence if you substituted `each` for `collect` in my last example, `elements` would be the original array of numbers (i.e. the same as `enumerable`), _not_ an array of numeric strings (i.e. what you would get by using `collect`).

Comment: I wasn't referring to the case you mentioned. `elements.each {|e| list << e.to_s }` does the same thing. I find it's just a matter of personal taste which method you're using.

Comment: Geo:  that's true about personal taste, but something can be said for how, with `collect`, you can initialize and populate an array in one step, whereas with `each` you must initialize an array beforehand.

Comment: @Tempus sometimes there is a difference. Try `a=[];b=1.upto(5).collect{|i|a<<i}`. Then try `1.upto(5).collect { |i| i }`. `a` is (eventually) correct, but only after it get evaluated 5 times. The latter returns an array as you'd expect.